# Custom android app theme with translucent notification and navigation bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, transparent, android-theme, android-4.4-kitkat

Since Android 4.4 was introduced I had this big question about translucent notification and navigation bar:

How do you make a custom theme so that the notification bar is the same color as the action bar as well as the navigation bar be the same color that the current activity is?

A good example of this is the Trello app:

[image]

And:

[image]

Even if you open a navigation drawer, the navigation bar still retains its color. How does one achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new (as of 4.4) `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor` or `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor` themes. Or you can set `windowTranslucentNavigation` in your theme. You'll also want to fill the area behind the system bars by setting `fitsSystemWindows` to true in your layout.

More info in the [Android 4.4 APIs changes document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI)